# How to refresh a package after changing the config.settings in Atom? (init.coffee script)

Tags: atom-editor

I'd like to add a command to Atom to quickly change the spell-checking language. To do so I use the given code in the init.coffee script. I found the right spot to change the config data.

My problem is that Atom (or spell-check) does not recognize the change. How do I tell the package: "the config changed, please refresh yourself"?

```js
atom.commands.add 'atom-workspace', 'Spell-DE', ->
  atom.config.settings['spell-check'].locales = ['de-DE']  
  sc = atom.packages.getLoadedPackage('spell-check')

  # sc.PLEASE_READ_SETTINGS_AGAIN(); <<< what could this be?
```

The change is recognized by Atom once I opened the spell-check-settings.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, got it: `atom.config.set('spell-check.locales', ['de-DE']);` is doing the trick.